# How to make horizontal scrollbar always appear on Flask-Admin dashboard regardless of content size?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

When there are too many fields, a horizontal scrollbar is needed for scrolling.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmBcx.png)
But now I'm facing an issue where, when there is too much data, I need to scroll to the bottom for the scrollbar to appear. How can I make the horizontal scrollbar always visible on the webpage?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gir0y.png)

I tried to modify the Flask-Admin documentation, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you set the height of the table to be less than the height of the screen?

Comment: If there is too much data, it will definitely exceed the screen.

Comment: Exactly. Make the table shorter than the page. Then your large table will then have scroll bars on the right and also on the bottom.

Comment: Since I am using the Flask-Admin package, the webpage style is designed by them. I tried to modify their CSS, but I couldn't find the correct CSS file.Is there any way to directly modify the webpage style through Flask-Admin's API?

Comment: `class FixProdView(AdminModelViewBASE):


    create_modal = True

    edit_modal = True

    can_view_details = True
    def form_widget_args(self, form, widget):
        if widget.kwargs.get('class') == 'table':
            widget.kwargs['style'] = 'height: 400px; overflow: auto;'
        return super(FixProdView, self).form_widget_args(form, widget)`

I tried to add this function to control the table shorter than the pages, but it seems didn't work.